# Can not use bs4 even after installing bs4 in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, module, pip, python-import

I install beautifulsoup and tried to use bs4 in VScode. I check the IDLE  where I can find the beautifulsoup but when I try to import in my vscode it is not running here is the picture
[image]

I am learning python and I am trying to solve this problem for the last 2 days. Please help me to solve this problem. I check this problem elsewhere and the solution over there did not work

Comment: Try to check which python interpreter VSCode is using. you need to configure your python interpreter to be the same one you installed BS4 on.

Comment: try to install it using `pip install beautifulsoup4` and check using `pip list`

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general good thing to do is creating a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for managing python packages.

You can then use the virtual environment in VSCode as the python [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) can auto-detect them/let you choose one:

Hope this can help you solve your dependency problem.

EDIT: as pointed out in a comment the content is links only here, I add the basics as to what you can do to manage venvs.

On unix-like systems in python3 (you may need to install an OS package to get the venv package, e.g. on Ubuntu sudo apt install python3-venv) you can use the following command to create a venv in the dir .venv:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
```

Then you need to use the new venv, on Unix like OSes to activate the previously created .venv you use:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

On windows you run the script:

```
./.venv/Scripts/activate
```

Then you can install your dependencies in the venv, in the case of bs4:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And then you can use the venv in VSCode. If you have the python extension VSCode will auto detect venvs in your current workdir. If it does not use ctrl + shift + P to open the command palette and then search for "Python: select interpreter", then give the path to the python binary in your venv e.g. ".venv/bin/python" or for Windows ".venv/Scripts/python.exe"